# Conversion of three channel binary image to three channel RGB image

Tags: python, opencv

Is there any `OpenCV` function to convert three channel binary image to 3 channel RGB image?
Here is my code where `disparitySGB.jpg` is a grayscale (3 channel image).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image=cv2.imread("disparitySGB.jpg")
thresh=cv2.inRange(image,np.array([89,89,89]),np.array([140,140,140]));
cv2.rectangle(np.array(thresh),(100,100),(120,120),(255,255,0),3)
cv2.imshow("thresh",thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```

`inRange` returns 8U image.My concern is that the rectangle drawn must be colored.In this case it is white.(I think it is because the image is three channel binary image).

Comment: your're right - you can only draw coloured things on 3channel mats. you probably need to : `thresh_col = cv2.cvtColor(thresh,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)` and then draw into that

Comment: I think the image is 3channel mat but its datatype is such it not accommodating colors,if it was a one channel mat there must be no contour.However in this case I am getting a white contour.

Comment: ok! that was my mistake, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR actually worked.Thank you so much for your help.:)

Comment: You can add this to answer and I will accept your answer as the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# my dummy channels:
r = np.ones((100,100),np.uint8)  * 100
g = np.ones((100,100),np.uint8)  * 70
b = np.ones((100,100),np.uint8)  * 10

#now, just merge them:
rgb = cv2.merge((r,g,b))
```

you can only draw coloured things on 3channel mats. you probably need to : thresh_col = cv2.cvtColor(thresh,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) and then draw into that

Comment: Thanx for the answer,but I want 'converting' not 'creating',I am adding some code so you might have a clear picture,of what I am asking.